# "Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" when trying to load a csv file on tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter

I have done a program on python using `tkinter` library. The new module launches a new tk window and shows a CSV table. The problem is that I always get the same error of:

```
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have changed the CSV file many times and I don't know what I should change.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter import *

def cargartabla(self):
    self.root=tkinter.Tk()
    self.root.title("Tabla Magnitudes")
    self.root.geometry("650x800")
    self.frame=tkinter.Frame(self.root)
    self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    self.pt=Table(self.frame)
    self.data = pd.read_csv(filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/home/username/Desktop",
        title="Open a File",
        filetypes=(("csv files", "*.csv"), ("all files", "*.*"))
    ))
    self.pt.importCSV(self.data)
    self.pt.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] and the full error traceback (starting from word "Traceback"), also don't use `from tkinter import *`, import what you exactly need or looking at your code just do `import tkinter`

Comment: It also looks like you're using a type called a `Table` which is not in the a standard library, so you need to specify what that is when asking questions — and I suspect that is the origin of the error you are getting.

Comment: Assume `Table` is the table widget from `pandastable`, then you need to pass the filename to `self.pt.importCSV()`, not a `DataFrame` (`self.data`).

Comment: Thank you so much.
@Matiiss - I'm gonna change the import in my code as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you @martineau , it was my fault. Table is the table widget from pandastable.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668, that was my mistake. I was trying to load a pandas dataframe instead the csv, your suggestion works correctly.